# Lis3dsh interrupt doesn’t pulse

Tags: accelerometer, st

I need to get a interrupt when some motion is detected. I tried example state machine from the application notes (wake up), and connected led to int1 for debugging. After setting all registers and shaking a bread board led started to glow. But it glow constantly, I have no oscilloscope unfortunately to check deeply. But in any case it continues to glow without any movements. Do I have some mistake in the state machine description, or do I have to reset it after each interrupt ( sounds weird)?

Comment: The state machines (there are two) in the LIS3 are complicated, with many options. I suspect that the "example state machine" is designed to latch the interrupt output until a command is sent to the LIS3 to reset it. But I can't be sure without more information. You're going to have to dive into the datasheet and application notes to better understand the device.

Answer (score 2):

This could be the latch issue, CTRL_REG3 value 0x48 -> 0x68.

I have a problem with pulsed INterrupt, the interrupt comes only one time and then I need to reset the board to get another single interrupt...

I do get interrupts when I set the INT1 pin to notify me when the next acceleration result is ready, but this happens in a constant rate I have set (100Hz).
The motion detection and interrupt still doesn't work which is weird to me. I have looked for this an answer but as many have asked this same question no answers found. I wonder is there an issue in this sensor...

Comment: Why don’t you use latched interrupt?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a few years old now, but I'm answering it just in case anyone else comes across it like myself.

You have to read the OUTSy register (where y is the state machine in use) to clear the interrupt.

From section 7.4 in [ST LIS3DSH application note AN3393](https://www.eng.auburn.edu/%7Enelsovp/courses/elec5260_6260/STM_Discovery/LIS3DSH_Accel_AppNote.pdf)

> The OUTSy register is cleared after reading itself. Moreover, by
> reading this register the interrupt status changes:
>
> - when the interrupt is latched (IEL bit = 0 in CTRL_REG3 register),
>   it becomes low (if it is active high) or high (if it is active low);
> - when the interrupt is pulsed (IEL bit = 1 in CTRL_REG3 register), a
>   new interrupt pulse can be generated. In fact, until register OUTSy
>   has not been read, no more interrupt can be generated.